# loop through a list with a function and store as variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of variables I need to run though a function to produce a json table. I want to loop through this list (list_db) and create a new variable to look through them manually in spyder. I am having trouble creating those new variables from the for loop. I thought i could use the name of the items in list as the new variable name, but i cant get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
for i in list_db:
    p = str(i) 
    p = getDF(i) #function to run
```

What am I missing? What is the more standard way of doing this i cant think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems variable names don't really act how you are expecting. When you do `p = str(i)`, you are assigning to the variable `p`. And then your next line, `p = getDF(i)` **overwrites** the value of `p`. It does **not** write to a variable whose name is `str(i)` like you are expecting.

If you want to store values into named slots, you can use a dictionary:

```
p = {}
for i in list_db:
    p[i] = getDF(i)
```